# ubuntu-gnome-16.04.3-desktop-amd64 USB installation problem

Tags: usb-installation

I'm trying to install ubuntu-gnome-16.04.3-desktop-amd64 on Windows 64 via USB stick.

When i try to "install Ubuntu", i get a screen like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sx58p.jpg (same when i select "try ubuntu") and nothing happens afterwards. I already updated my BIOS (asus b150m-k)

I'd be glad to hear your comments.
Thanks in Advance

---

### System Information

```
  Time of this report: 8/19/2017, 12:42:07
         Machine name: DESKTOP-09H2588
           Machine Id: {6B6C5EC4-9E66-437E-9FB7-B4EBE5A85B4C}
     Operating System: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit (10.0, Build 15063) (15063.rs2_release.170317-1834)
             Language: Turkish (Regional Setting: Turkish)
  System Manufacturer: System manufacturer
         System Model: System Product Name
                 BIOS: 3016
            Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6500 CPU @ 3.20GHz (4 CPUs), ~3.2GHz
               Memory: 16384MB RAM
  Available OS Memory: 16312MB RAM
            Page File: 2649MB used, 16093MB available
          Windows Dir: C:\WINDOWS
      DirectX Version: DirectX 12
  DX Setup Parameters: Not found
     User DPI Setting: Using System DPI
   System DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
      DWM DPI Scaling: Disabled
             Miracast: Available, with HDCP
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by removing `quiet splash` with `nomodeset` in the `Install Ubuntu Parameters`